# Create image with dd command .cow2

Tags: dd

Using dd command, it possible to create image of type  .vdi, .qcow, .qcow2, .vhd, .vhdx and .vmdk instead of .img?

```
dd if=/dev/hda of=/path/to/desti.**qcow2 or .vhmdk** etc formats
```

Thank you,
Answers Appreciated

Comment: I am not sure if this can be done, but, you could read the man pages for dd, use `man dd` and see if it says something about output formats. However, I think you can specify the output format manually, no matter what it is, try for example, using a different extension for the output file, and then do the reverse process to see if the image works. Best regards.

Answer (score 7):

You may first create a raw image via `dd`, and then convert to any supported format via `qemu-img` e.g.:

`dd if=/dev/hda of=/path/to/dir/hda.raw
 qemu-img convert -O qcow2 /path/to/dir/hda.raw /path/to/dir/hda.qcow2`

Or to save disk space omit the dd part: `qemu-img` can read directly from disk:

`qemu-img convert -O qcow2 /dev/hda /path/to/dir/hda.qcow2`

In both cases a virtual disk in qcow2 format is created. To see a list of supported formats and options, see `man qemu-img`. Maybe you have to execute the commands prefixed by `sudo` to get access to `/dev/hda`.

Answer (score 0):

No you cannot, with one exception.

`dd` is a very simple program which simply copies bytes from an input file to an output file, optionally making simple transformations such as swapping bytes, mapping upper-case ASCII letters to lower-case or vice-versa, or transcoding between ASCII and EBCDIC. It has absolutely no notion of a file format; for `dd` a file is simply a sequence of bytes. Use `man dd` for more info.

There is a kind of VMware virtual disk which is called "flat" (specifically, `monolithicFlat` and `twoGbMaxExtentFlat`). "Flat" [VMware virtual disks](http://sanbarrow.com/vmdk/disktypes.html) *actually are* direct block-for-block images of a hard disk; they consist of at least two files: a description file (a text file with the extension `.vmdk`) and one or more data files. You can use `dd` to copy the data from a hard disk to a data file, create a suitable description file (easy to do) and use that data file (possibly split into several extents, if you wish) as a "flat" VMware virtual disk. As far as I know, you can use such virtual disks with VirtualBox too.

Comment: I have question: If I create VirtualBox Virtual disk for SD cards, would the guest OS will have write access to SD card? Because right now, I have read access but not write access.